# Caption for tabulate

Tags: captions, context

I am using `tabulate` to make a table that spans a few pages, but I need to place a caption over that table. Putting it inside `\startplacetable` and `\stopplacetable` makes it float, which is not wanted. I am unsure what to do because I have never used tabulate or made any long tables before. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using tabulate to make a table that spans a few pages, but I need to place a caption over that table.

[From the wiki:](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Tabulate#Titles)

> #### Titles
>
> A tabulating environment can have an optional name which will be
> repeated above at every page break that occurs inside the table. This
> name needs to be specified as the argument of the title key of
> `\setuptabulate`. The header key has to be set to text for this to
> work.
>
> ```tex
> \setuppapersize[A10, landscape][A8, landscape]
> \setuppaper[nx=2,ny=2]
> \setuparranging[XY]
>
> \switchtobodyfont[5pt]
> \setuppagenumbering[location={header,inright}]
> \showframe[edge]
>
> \setuptabulate
>    [split=yes,
>     header=text,
>     title={\color[red]{Fenchurch St. Paul}\strut},
>     frame=on]
>
> \starttext
> \starttabulate[|p(1.2cm)|p(1.2cm)|]
> \dorecurse{6}{
>   \NC  Bells:  \NC  Tin tan din dan bim bam bom bo \NC\NR
>   \HL
>   \NC  Name:  \NC  Tailor Paul \NC \NR                                              
>   \HL
> }
> \stoptabulate
> \stoptext
> ```

[image: code output]

> Putting it inside `\startplacetable` and `\stopplacetable` makes it float, which is not wanted.

You can use `location=force` to make a “float” not actually float:

```tex
% To show multiple pages in a single page
\setuppapersize[A6][A4]
\setuppaper[nx=2, ny=2]
\setuparranging[XY]
\showframe[edge]

% Set up the table formatting
\setupcaptions[table][location=top]
\setupfloat[table][align=middle]

\starttext
    \startplacetable[
        title={Table title},
        location={force, split},
    ]
        \startTABLE[
            split=yes,
            leftframe=off,
            rightframe=off
        ]
            \dorecurse{10}{
                \NC One   \NC Two   \NC\NR
                \NC Three \NC Four  \NC\NR
                \NC Five  \NC Six   \NC\NR
                \NC Seven \NC Eight \NC\NR
                \NC Nine  \NC Ten   \NC\NR
            }
        \stopTABLE
    \stopplacetable
\stoptext
```

[image: code output]

Comment: I may not be clear., sorry. I need the caption that will show in List of Table. The caption should just appear once of course.

Comment: @MuhammadRizqiSiregar The second solution should show up in the list of tables. You might need to add a `reference=` key to make it work though.

Comment: Missed the ```reference=``` part. This works perfectly. Thanks.